# Issue with recyler view

Tags: android

My recycler view gets inside the tab layout

[image]

I have issue with Recylerview.What should I do to overcome this problem.
I am new android developer. Unable to rectify this issue. I had three xml file one for toolbar, fragment ,main activity.

My fragment-

```
    public class viewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitlles= new ArrayList<>();
    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments,String titles){
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitlles.add(titles);
    }

  public viewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
      super(fm);
  }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitlles.get(position);
    }
```

My Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
viewPagerAdapter vp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.inactive), getResources().getColor(R.color.active));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Customer App");

        vp= new viewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
vp.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"homr");
        vp.addFragments(new topfreeFragment(),"top");
        vp.addFragments(new TopPaidFragment(),"paid");
        viewPager.setAdapter(vp);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

My pageadapter

```
    public class viewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> tabTitlles= new ArrayList<>();
        public void addFragments(Fragment fragments,String titles){
            this.fragments.add(fragments);
            this.tabTitlles.add(titles);
        }

      public viewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
          super(fm);
      }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabTitlles.get(position);
        }
    }
public class viewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitlles= new ArrayList<>();
    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments,String titles){
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitlles.add(titles);
    }

  public viewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
      super(fm);
  }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitlles.get(position);
    }
}
```

My fragment Xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="test.fmtest.HomeFragment"
>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/lis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

My Activity XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="test.fmtest.MainActivity">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">
     <include
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"></include>
     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/tablayout"
         app:tabMode="fixed"
         app:tabGravity="fill">

     </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: I cant see recycler view anywhere in the added code snippet\

Comment: See my XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with same Constraintlayout(use this for responsive UI).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <include
                        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
                />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```